# How to call GetInvocationList() in the following code?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

The class hierarchy and the code is like the below：
And how to call GetInvocationList() to see how many functions have been bound to the Added delegation in the Main function?

```
namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class SelectSet
        {
            public event SelectSet.AddedEventHandler Added;
            public delegate void AddedEventHandler(object BusinessObject);
        }

        public class C1
        {
            public static SelectSet SelectSet;
        }

        static void Main()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> And how to call GetInvocationList() to see how many functions have been binded to the Added delegation in the Main function?

You can't (at least without reflection), and you shouldn't. The point of exposing an *event* is to only expose functionality to add or remove handlers. So it's a bit like your code was written like this:

```
public class SelectSet
{
    // Private fields here

    public void AddAddedHandler(SelectSet.AddedEventHandler handler)
    {
        // Implement using private fields
    }

    public void RemoveAddedHandler(SelectSet.AddedEventHandler handler)
    {
        // Implement using private fields
    }

    public delegate void AddedEventHandler(object BusinessObject);
}
```

If you look at *that* class, it's pretty obvious that from the outside you won't be able to find out what handlers there are. Just because you're declaring a field-like event doesn't give the outside world access to your field.

You can expose the handlers explicitly if you want, of course - but it's rarely a good idea.

See my [article on events and delegates](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In VB at least, the delegate is available as `Private <EventName>Event`, so you could retrieve `AddedEvent.GetInvocationList` directly from within the class, or using reflection from outside.